# What jet is pictured on the FAA pilot certificate?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-identification, usa, faa

The front of the FAA pilot certificate shows two aircraft.  One is the Wright Flyer.  The other appears to be a 2 or 3 engine commercial jet.  What model of aircraft is that jet?  The engines look longer than any of those in common use today.
[image]

Comment: https://books.google.cz/books?id=UOhMBNM5LI8C&lpg=PA31&ots=WegaBa5_GK&dq=%22airmen%20certificate%22%20%22wright%20brothers%22&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false "a jumbo jet"

Comment: @Richard I read that article (from your link) referring to the jet as being a "jumbo jet," e.g., a B747? Interesting. But the image seems to show only two engines?

Comment: @757toga - I posted it without comment because I don't know anything about planes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like a Boeing 737-100 or Boeing 737-200.

[image]
(737-100, source: [allaboutlean.com](https://www.allaboutlean.com/boeing-management/lufthansa-boeing-737-100/))

[image]
(737-200, source: [airplane-pictures.net](https://www.airplane-pictures.net/type.php?p=10))

Comment: Thanks! That does look like the closest match.  I was looking at McDonnell Douglas & Lockheed as well as Boeing assuming it would have been a US manufacturer, but I didn't see these earlier variants.

Comment: It is most likely a -200. There were only 30 -100 built and they were all overseas (20 to Lufthansa). The only other -100 was the Boeing flight test aircraft (a -130) that was donated to NASA and used there for years. It was retired in 2003 and is at the Museum of Flight in Seattle in the NASA livery. The photo on the certificate is definitely not the NASA livery. There were 1114 -200 built and a number are still in service. So odds favor the -200. There's not enough detail in the image to distinguish between them, the difference being 73 inches overall length.

Comment: @Gerry See the link below the OP's question. Could the airplane image be a "jumbo jet" (e.g., B747) with only two engines visible?

Comment: I don't think so. The proportions are all wrong when compared to a B767/777. I found this pic of a -200 from a similar angle; [B737-200](https://flyawaysimulation.com/images/add-ons/21678/britanniazip-0-ss3.jpg)

Comment: @Gerry I don't disagree.  The image does look like a B737-100 or B737-200.

Comment: Okay, but WHY is this jet on the pilot certificate? Does it have some historic value that puts it in league with the Wright Flyer?